# Derivative of a products with matrix exponential

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus

I should find the derivative with respect to the vector $a \in  \mathbb{R}^{n}$

$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial a}(a^{T}exp(aa^{T})a)$

Answer should be in a matrix form

I tried to decompose the expression into a derivative of products, but $\dfrac{\partial a}{\partial a}$ looks strange

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint :

Tailor's Theorem gives
\begin{align*}
\exp(aa^T)&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!} (aa^T)^n\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!} a (a^T a)^{n-1} a^T\\
&=a \left( \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!} (\lVert a \rVert^2)^{n-1} \right) a^T\\
&=\frac{1}{\lVert a \rVert^2} a \left( \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!} (\lVert a \rVert^2)^{n} \right) a^T\\
&=\frac{\exp(\lVert a \rVert^2)}{\lVert a \rVert^2} aa^T
\end{align*}

So that
\begin{align*}
a^T \exp(aa^T) a &= \lVert a \rVert^2 \exp(\lVert a \rVert^2)
\end{align*}